# Full text not displaying after a quote

Tags: php

I've got an item in a database that has a quote in it and when it displays on the page that's calling it, it cuts out a quote in the entry and everything after it. This is what's in the database:

```
5' & Under P&S
```

All that gets outputted is just the 5. Silly mistake, just need to make it escape the quote, right? Apparently not. I tried looking it up with google and came across a few solutions like addslashes() and htmlentities(), but they don't seem to work. Using them I go from just the 5 to

```
5\
```

with the remainder of the data missing. What can I do?

here's my code for outputting, sans the addslashes/htmlentities, which didn't work.

```
echo "<td><input type='text' name='mName' value='" . $row['name'] ."'></td>";
```

Comment: Can you post the PHP code you're using to output the string?

Comment: Insert it into your table with slashes.

Comment: How are you storing the value. Did you verify that it is what you think it is in the db? How are you retrieving the value?

Comment: do a var_dump() on the data to see, if the expected data is present after the sql select.
post the response in your question.

Comment: Are you *sure* the value in the database includes everything after the quote?  If the *insert* into the database was truncated at the quote, that's a *classic* symptom of SQL injection problems.

Comment: Where you are outputting it matters. If it is inside a `value=` attribute for example, you might see this behavior. Use the `ENT_QUOTES` option as `htmlentities($your_string, ENT_QUOTES)`

Comment: Ah yes, it actually is inside a value attribute. Now it's showing the full text, including the backslash. Anyway to avoid that?

Comment: Oh also, when you add something to database, it keeps its quotes, so no worries about SQL injection there.

Comment: If you see a backslash, it is probably because the data had a superfluous `addslashes()` when it was inserted, in addition to being escaped by the DB API.  You'll have to use `stripslashes()` to get rid of that backslash.